# How to call the function to display dynamic contents of first tab using angular bootstrap when the form / window loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using angualr bootstrap tab , I know ng-click event on tab fires any function on click of tab.

I want some dynamic content to be loaded on the first tab when form loads . The HTML is:

```
  <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.testData">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <title> Tabs</title>
   <link href="css/en/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
   <link href="css/en/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
   <link href="css/en/ng-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="css/en/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="css/en/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/en/icon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/en/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
    <body>
     <form id="formTabs" runat="server">
  <div>
        <div ng-controller="TabsDataCtrl">
          <hr />
          <tabset align="left">
           <tab heading="Account" ng-click ="ShowAccount()">
                <div id ="divAccount">
                    <div id ="TestAcccount"  style="padding-top:30px;" align ="center">
                     <table  id="PNRDataGrid" width="100%"></table>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </tab>
               <tab heading="Policy">Policy content
                    <div>
                    <table border ="1" style ="background-color :blue"><tr><td> Test</td></tr>
                   </table>
                    </div>
             </tab>
               <tab heading="LoB" ng-click ="ShowLob()">LOB content
                </div>
              </tab>
             <tab heading="Coverage">Coverage content</tab>
            <tab heading="Detailed Loss">Detailed Loss</tab>
           </tabset>
        </div>
      </div>
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
 <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/LossHistory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/DataScrolling.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.easyui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The js file is:

```
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.testData', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.testData').controller('TabsDataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.businessUnits = [];
$scope.lossHistory = [];

$scope.ShowAccount = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;

    var svcAccountURL = LHServiceDir + 
    '/Portal/WebServices/LossHistoryServices/LossHistoryServices.asmx/GetDetails';

  ....
  ....
  }
```

Is there any tab event which would fire on load of form or any other way which could fire the ShowAccount  function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like ng-init

```
     <div ng-init="ShowAccount()">
        // all your tabs here
     </div>
```

Assuming that ShowAccount() just goes off and then fills in some data, that data will then be ready for display as soon as the page comes up.
You can also just call "ShowAccount()" at the end of your controller and it will be called when your controller loads.

Comment: Why does it not work. I can't help you if I don't know why. I do something like this and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `angular.element(document).ready(function(){ ... })` in one of the controllers:

Code Snippet:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('In Angular Element Ready');
    myInitFunction();
});
```

This works for me in Chrome, although I have seen issues in Firefox.